# How to enable minification of xml and json files during apk build process?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

Our app contains a lot of `json` and `xml` in `res/raw` and `assets` folders (16 Mb unpacked). They are pretty formatted. When I minifiy them through external tool and analyze apk via apk-analyzer, the end file size is considerably lower.

Is there a way to enable such minification automatically during build process? 
Proguard, R8 and AGP doesn't seem to provide such functionality

my build.gradle

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    shrinkResources true
}
```

Comment: I've started related issue on aosp bug tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150555536 feel free to star =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DexGuard or
try adding this to your gradle file

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I already have this settings enabled and also             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
but that doesn't seem to work to minify xml and json. Updated a question